# Changing values in fields based on wild card searches between two tables

Tags: sql, windows-7, visual-foxpro

I want to set the `chosen` field to `true` in table *e:\ctw* for all records of field `name` which are not like `name2` in the *d:\le* table. The 'ctw.name' records have equal or more characters than the `le.name2` records so I want to implement wild card searches; for example,

le.name2 = abc,

ctw.name = abc\12a

So, I want to use a wild card search like 'abc%', but without hard coding a record value. That is, I want to know whether it is possible to combine a field name with wildcard search as below:

```
UPDATE ctw SET chosen = .t. WHERE LOWER(name) NOT LIKE ((select LOWER(name2) from le)+'%')
```

I get a `function name is missing )` error upon command input.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
SET ANSI OFF    
UPDATE ctw ;
   SET chosen = .t. 
   WHERE LOWER(name) NOT IN (select LOWER(name2) from le)
```

Comment: Hi Tamar,
I am not sure but OP wants to set those that starts with le.name2 to .T.?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you mean:

```
UPDATE ctw SET chosen = .t. ;
from le ;
where LOWER(name) LIKE lower(trim(le.Name2))+'%'
```

And because, by default VFP comparisons in SQL are not ANSI this would mean the same:

```
UPDATE ctw SET chosen = .t. ;
from le ;
where LOWER(name) = lower(trim(le.Name2))
```

But I wouldn't trust the non-ANSI implementation and use the ANSI implementation with LIKE.